# Changing the value of a PL SelectIO pin with the PS

Tags: fpga, xilinx, zynq

Using the Zynq architecture,

Is there a way to tie a PL SelectIO pin directly to memory address shared by the PS and the PL ?

Let's say address 0x000FFFF holds a std:vector  0101

I want PL selectIO pins to reflect the address 0x000FFFF so it can be controlled by the PS

AE9 ->  1st bit in address 0x000FFFF = 1

AE10 -> 2nd bit in address 0x000FFFF = 0

AE11 -> 3rd bit in address 0x000FFFF = 1

AE12 -> 4th bit in address 0x000FFFF = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate an AXI GPIO module and connect it to the pins you want to control.